# What model carburetor is this? (Mikuni Corp)

Tags: part-identification, carburetor, yamaha

Recently, my ATV (a 1997 Yamaha Big Bear 350 2x4) developed a carburetor issue where it would run rich. I took it to a mechanic who says that it needs a new carburetor. However, he was unable to find one.

**Manufacturer:** Mikuni Corp.
**Model Number (partial):**
*First Line:* `4WU 20`
*Second Line:* `???42`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there any way I can get the full model number of this carburetor?

Comment: I don't have the part number, but here's a [link to the carb](http://www.everestpartssupplies.com/products/1997-1998-yamaha-350-big-bear-carburetor-carb-yfm-350-2x4-atv-yfm350-f1?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=googlepla&variant=1036410705&gclid=Cj0KEQjw-tSrBRCk8bzDiO__gbwBEiQAk-D31S-SNA6w7tEg8NrviCgKFIxmCg9k5_hQE2huStlYfLoaAmmq8P8HAQ). Just remember, Google is your friend.

Comment: @Paulster2 It looks similar, but that one (at least in the pictures) has a different top to it. I'll order it and give it a try though.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly the same to work. The description for usage is spot on.

Comment: @insertusernamehere - Here's one.    http://www.everestpartssupplies.com/products/1997-1998-yamaha-350-big-bear-carburetor-carb-yfm-350-2x4-atv-yfm350-f1?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=googlepla&variant=1036410705&gclid=CjwKEAjw2cOsBRD3xNbRp5eQxzYSJADZGYbzJmc_1olc-MZ-RVAq6nyF0uqjeWeBhLzy3XNadTyD3hoCGyXw_wcB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the part number for your carb.  This is for an OEM Yamaha carb.

3HN-14101-00-00

[image]